Python get data using column name instead of column index
I have the following Python code to get data from database. I need to get data from Cursor, using column name description.
try:
    with _db.connect() as cnn:
        crr = cnn.cursor()
        crr.execute(
            "SELECT Frame, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Frame ASC),[Left Elbow Ulnar Deviation/Radial Deviation],[Left Elbow Pronation/Supination],"
            "[Left Elbow Flexion/Extension],[Left T4 Shoulder Abduction/Adduction],[Left T4 Shoulder Internal/External Rotation],"
            "[Left T4 Shoulder Flexion/Extension],[Right T4 Shoulder Abduction/Adduction],[Right T4 Shoulder Internal/External Rotation]"
            "FROM AA_V_SHWS_RulaSensorDataXValues r "
            "WHERE idRulaSensorData = ? ",(idFileImportato))
        rows = crr.fetchall()
        if rows is None or len(rows) == 0:
            logger.error(f"File [{idFileImportato}] file import not found in Omnia")
            return False
        for row in rows:
            #
            Flex_Sh = row.cursor_description('C86')# 
except Exception as x:
    logger.error(f"File [{idMonitoraggio}] Error in query to get data: {x}")
    return False

I need to get data from "row" using column name but I m not able to do it.

Many connection packages provide a DictCursor class or similar, but we need to know which package you are using to point you to the right answer.
